# C programming File size

Tags: c, file, filesize

I am trying to acquire the size of a file after creating it and writing data to it. I get values that don't seem to correspond to the actual file size. Here is my program. Please show me how I can display the file size in Bits, Bytes, Kilobytes, and Megabytes. According to me the file size should be 288 Bits, 36 Bytes, 0.03515626 Kilobytes, and 0.000034332 Megabytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define PERMS 0777

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int createDescriptor;
    int openDescriptor;

    char fileName[15]="Filename1.txt";
    umask(0000);

    if ((openDescriptor = creat(fileName, PERMS )) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error creating %s", fileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if(write(openDescriptor,"This will be output to testfile.txt\n",36 ) != 36)
    {
        write(2,"There was an error writing to testfile.txt\n",43);
        return 1;
    }

    if((close(openDescriptor))==-1)
    {
        write(2, "Error closing file.\n", 19);
    }
    struct stat buf;
    fstat(openDescriptor, &buf);
    int size=buf.st_size;
    printf("%d\n",size);
    printf("%u\n",size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `fstat` on a `close`d _descriptor_, is that intentional? Seems you should be `close`-ing `createDescriptor` instead...

Answer (score 7):

The `fstat()` function has a return code, **check it.**

```
int r = fstat(openDescriptor, &buf);
if (r) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: fstat: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

This will print:

```
error: fstat: Bad file descriptor
```

Yep... you closed the file descriptor, it's not a file descriptor any more.  You have to `fstat()` before calling `close()`.

### The code worries me.

This is extremely fragile, and cannot be recommended under any circumstances:

```
if (write(openDescriptor,"This will be output to testfile.txt\n",36 ) != 36)
```

You can do this:

```
const char *str = "This will be output to testfile.txt\n";
if (write(fd, str, strlen(str)) != strlen(str))
```

It will compile to the same machine code, and it's obviously correct (as opposed to the original code, where you have to count the number of characters in a string to figure out if it's correct or not).

Even better, when you are using `stderr`, just use the standard `<stdio.h>` functions:

```
fprintf(stderr, "There was an error writing to %s: %s\n",
        fileName, strerror(errno));
```

The same error appears when defining `fileName`...

```
// You should never have to know how to count higher than 4 to figure
// out if code is correct...
char fileName[15]="Filename1.txt";

// Do this instead...
static const char fileName[] = "Filename1.txt";
```

You actually miscounted this time, `[15]` should have been `[14]`, but better to leave it to the compiler.  There's no benefit to making the compiler's job easier, since the compiler presumably doesn't have better things to do.

### About the machine code:

```
$ cat teststr.c
#include <unistd.h>
void func(int openDescriptor) {
    write(openDescriptor,"This will be output to testfile.txt\n",36 );
}
$ cat teststr2.c
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void func(int openDescriptor) {
    const char *str = "This will be output to testfile.txt\n";
    write(openDescriptor, str, strlen(str));
}
$ cc -S -O2 teststr.c
$ cc -S -O2 teststr2.c
$ diff teststr.s teststr2.s
1c1
<       .file   "teststr.c"
---
>       .file   "teststr2.c"
```

Yep.  As demonstrated, the call to `strlen()` does not actually result in different machine code.

Comment: Don't call `strlen` twice for the same string if the string isn't changing. `strlen` is quite an "expensive" function to call, so it should be avoided whenever possible - although for a constant, the compiler may calculate it, risk is that someone thinks this is a good plan for a variable as well [I do agree that using hard-coded constants for strings is a much worse alternative than calling strlen twice].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You're not paying attention.  The whole point is that the string is constant.  It's also **not** expensive, not compared to the other tasks this program performs.

Comment: Yes, and my suggestion is still to not call strlen twice for a constant string, because someone will change it to a non-constant string and continue calling strlen twice, and then you don't get the same good side-effect of the compiler calculating it during compilation.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes, there are lots of people who copy and paste code without understanding it.  (1) I don't care about these people.  (2) These people will make other, more serious mistakes so it is a waste of time to help them in advance.  (3) Code should be correct before it is optimized.  (4) Code should be profiled before it is optimized.  It is a waste of time to optimize unprofiled code for theoretical future cases in which the code is modified.  I will not encourage programmers to waste time on such things when they could spend that time eating dinner with their families.

Comment: But writing `size_t len = strlen(str);` and using len in the two places is not unduly difficult - in fact, it makes it easier to see that it's the same value meant in both places.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It sounds like you are gung-ho about source code reviews, since you keep on telling me how to write code even after I explain why I don't care (read the part where I talk about optimizing unprofiled code for "theoretical future cases" -- and how that sets a bad example).  Why not apply your efforts to an open-source project?  I'm sure they would appreciate any bugs you might catch.  I can see that you understand the semantics of C code, and there are plenty of productive opportunities for someone with your talents.  And you won't have to deal with grumpy ol' me.